# Got 'Error getting file: -7: I/O problem' on one file (I guess) while transferring photos via usb cable from Android to Debian 10

Tags: debian, android, mtp

I was getting a libmtp copy error until I switched usb transfer mode on Android 10 from file to photo. Then everything seemed to start copying fine, but during the process I got that error and just hit 'skip' (default file manager when you install Debian with only 'Debian Desktop' chosen as a DE), and can't tell if all files were copies or not.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused:

- bad USB cable or port
- bugs in the libtmp library
- storage errors on your phone

In the past I struggled with this so much, I've long switched to [FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.swiftp)

You may also try using [Android File Transfer For Linux](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux) which some people say is more reliable.

Comment: Does FTP Server work via usb cable?

Comment: FTP Server allows you to connect to your phone via a WiFi connection. I've given you a second option as well.

Comment: @Daniel or better, enable [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) on your device, and use adb push/pull/shell. Most Linux distros have an adb client as a package, you don't have to install the whole Android SDK just for this.

Comment: Since `adb` normally works via USB (though a wireless connection is possible in late Android releases) it's also prone to USB connection issues. Also it's extremely cumbersome to work with it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov HTF is it "extremely cumbersome"? more or less cumbersome than creating a google play account and installing random apps? (Oh yeah, you could also install apps without google play ... if you're using `adb install`).

Comment: @Daniel if "FTP Server" is what its name suggests, it should work via an usb cable by setting your device in "tethering mode" and then connecting on the PC to its "gateway" address (the default route of `ip route show dev <the_usb_interface>`).